# Custom favicon not displaying in Angular 16

Tags: angular, favicon

I am new to front-end web development and I'm trying to make a website in Angular. So far I've gotten as far as creating a default Angular app using the CLI, with `ng new my-app`, and I was trying to modify the website icon from the default Angular `favicon.ico`.

Here are the changes I made:

1. I generated a custom icon using an online generator from a PNG file, and saved it in `my-app/src/favicon-16x16.png`
2. I modified the `<head>` tag of the `index.html` file as follows:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16" href="src/favicon-16x16.png" type="image/png" />
```

Unfortunately despite trying it in a bunch of different ways, Angular is still displaying the default icon when I serve the app locally using `ng serve`. I thought this might be an issue with the local instance, so I tried hosting it on GitHub Pages under {my-app}.github.io, and there it simply has no icon at all.

Help is much appreciated, I've been trying to resolve this for several hours now, and I'm pretty sure there's a simple error I'm missing somewhere.

Comment: I would place the icon to **src/assets/** folder, since **Angular** uses this path to serve static assests. So move **favicon-16x16.png** to **src/assets/** path. Now you need to update the link in **index.html** to: 
`<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16" href="assets/favicon-16x16.png" type="image/png" />`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I also read about how Angular only recognizes assets in **src/assets** folder since version 9. I tried doing as you say, however, and I still can't see the custom icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At long last, I figured out the issue. For some reason, when I ran the local instance on Safari at http://localhost:4200/, the favicon did not display, but when I ran it on Chrome at the same URL, it displayed without issues.

I'm unsure why this is the case or how to fix it on Safari, but I assume it wasn't something I could've solved with my code, but rather a browser issue. Thanks to everyone who posted solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Save your custom icon in the src/assets i.e.:
my-app/src/ assets/favicon-16x16.png

Open the angular.json file in your project's root directory.

Find the assets section in the architect.build.options configuration. It should look something like this:

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
```

If “src/favicon.ico isn’t there, then add it.

In the src/index.html file, locate the <link> tag for the favicon (it should be inside the <head> section).

Change the href attribute i.e.:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: I'm afraid the icon is still not showing up. In VS Code when I CTRL + Click on the `href` address, it doesn't lead me anywhere. I tried modifying the `href` to equal "src/assets/favicon.ico", and now I see the image when I CTRL + Click, and yet still running `ng serve` I can't see the custom icon.

Comment: It seems there’s something else going on. HREF should point to where your fav icon.ico is. That should work. I’m puzzled, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Copy or move the custom image *(ex. fav.png)* to the **/src** directory. Modify the href attribute to like this in your **index.html**

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="fav.png">
```

Then go to your project **angular.json** file look for the assets configuration properties and modify from

```
// other angular configuration
"assets":[
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
// other angular configuration
```

to this

```
// other angular configuration
"assets":[
  "src/fav.png",
  "src/assets"
],
// other angular configuration
```

Stop the app if it is running and redeploy it. Once you do, it will display no Icon. Close and reopen your browser to apply the changes. I discovered that the changes do not take effect if your browser is running already before the modification.

Comment: This is also a valid point, good call.